# why use akka eventhandler for logging

Tags: java, scala, logging, actor, akka

In the following document, event handlers are described as taking the place of logging
http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/general/event-handler.html

> There is an Event Handler which takes the place of a logging system in Akka:
>
> akka.event.EventHandler

Specifically, this link provides an example of how to do this while using slf4j:
http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/general/slf4j.html

My question is 'what advantages does this give? 'why would I do this instead of just using a logger using the standard pattern?'

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyActor.class);
...
log.info("doing something");
```

Is there some kind of underlying benefit I'd get, based on threading or dispatcher internals, by using an event-handler over the above logger pattern that I'm not seeing?  If not, using an event-handler for logging feels like deviating from a familiar pattern for no clear reason.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Logging generally means IO, which can slow down the operations of your code. In the context of an actor where each message must be processed single-file in your receive method, this overhead can, in some cases, make an order (or more) of magnitude difference in the time for that method to complete. It's already a common pattern within Erlang-based systems to move the logging outside of the flow of control of the thread (or process, in the Erlang sphere) that is running the receive block. If your actors are not heavily dependent on the timing of the receive block, you can always fall back to the standard logging pattern if that makes things easier for you, but it's probably a good idea to get used to the EventHandler-based approach.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that makes good sense.  I went ahead and changed the logging in my actors to use the EventHandler.info() etc methods.  It doesn't seem to be respecting my pattern layout specified in my log4j.xml file, but I'm seeing my INFO level messages at least.

Comment: Asynchronous logging sounds a little dangerous. What guarantee do I have that a) log statements come out in the correct order and b) that the EventHandler is able to keep up with the rest of the system (if logging is the slowest part of the system, the log queue will just grow and grow until an OutOfMemory happens).  Does it make sense to log errors synchronously?

Comment: If you depend on a specific sequencing or guarantees about ordering, perhaps an actor-based approach is not right for you. That said, since logging is itself handled by an actor and actors are given their messages in the order they were received, this should not be a problem. Further, Akka has a very solid message queueing implementation that's also adjustable/tunable to your needs. If you're worried about overflowing the buffer (I'm not sure what limits Akka has by default) you can use a bounded message queue and create your own logging handler that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

@DParsin, you would need to have application.conf file in your classpath with at least the following:

```
akka {
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
    loglevel = DEBUG
    stdout-loglevel = INFO
}
```

and then of course also make sure you are using logback (or slf4j-log4j etc.).
If you have logback-classic-1.0.0.jar in your classpath, make sure that you do NOT have any other SLF4J adapters in your classpath too.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using Slf4jEventHandler in Akka 1.2.  You lose the ability to set logging levels on a per class basis versus

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyActor.class);
...
log.info("doing something");
```

Reason being Slf4jEventHandler uses only one logger with the name of "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"